# Using Jquery to subtract values from HTML table without backend

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use jquery to subtract `-1` or a certain value from a `<td>` in an HTML table.

I managed to declare these two variables in an on click event. but my problem is continuously updating the value of the `<td>` every time I press the `-1` button.

Here is the declaration of variables.

```
$(".minusOneBtn").click(function() {
    var totalUses = $(".remaining").html(); 
    var subtractedUses = totalUses - 1;
});
```

Here is the the pen https://codepen.io/Gallad23/pen/vaQGoL

Comment: So you want to update your <td> value after you subtract one?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please, not codepen

Comment: exactly everytime I press on that -1 button I need to update the <td> with the new value

Comment: `html()` returns a string, not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work in appropriate row and actually change the html I believe

```js
$(".minusOneBtn").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find(".remaining").text(function(_, currTxt) {
    // TODO: validate currTxt or hide button when none left
    return currTxt - 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="remaining">10</td>
    <td><button class="minusOneBtn"> -1</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="remaining">7</td>
    <td><button class="minusOneBtn"> -1</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get remaining in row, then subtract from that

```
$(".minusOneButton").on('click', function() {
  var $remaining = $(this).parent().parent().find(".remaining");
  var totalUses = $remaining.html(); 
  var subtractedUses = totalUses - 1;
  $remaining.text(subtractedUses);
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBERMK